# Spark custom Encoder - can I drop/rename columns

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am writing a def that lets users import rows into a case class from JDBC by specifying the case class type only (I will provide the encoders)

The column names are in French and I would like to know if it is possible to write an encoder that converts a dataframe with columns `name1 -> T1`, `name2 -> T2`... into a Dataset[T] where T is a case `class SomeCaseClass(name1': T1, name2': T2...)`

To summarise I may want to rename or omit some columns but types will not change.

I realise I can do something like the following:

```
spark.sqlContext.read
  .format("jdbc")
  .option("driver", jdbcConfig.driver)
  .option("url", jdbcConfig.url)
  .option("dbtable", table)
  .option("user", jdbcConfig.user)
  .option("password", jdbcConfig.password)
  .load
  .toDF(Utils.caseClassConstructorParams[T].keys.toSeq: _*)
  .as[T]
```

however this seems less efficient, I can't drop columns and I cant guarantee columns will be returned in the same order as my case class constructor parameters.

Cheers for any advice.